# how to evaluate and get accuracy of a Feed forward neural network with pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, linear-regression

I started using Pytorch and I'm currently working on a Project where I'm using a simple feed forward neural network for linear regression. The Problem is I didn't find anything in Pytorch that allows me to get the Accuracy of a linear regression Model as in Keras or in SKlearn. in keras it would be simple just by setting `metrics=["accuracy"]` inside the compile function. I searched in the docs and official website of Pytorch but I didn't find anything. seems that this API doesn't exist in Pytorch. I know that I can observe the loss during training or I can simply get the test loss and based on it I can know whether the loss decreased or not but I want to use that Keras Structure where I get the loss value and also an Accuracy value. the Keras way looks more clear. I also tried to implement an accuracy function using the r2_score from sklearn but it gave me wierd values:

```
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3, momentum=0.9)

def train(model, optimizer, loss_fn):
    def train_step(x, y):
        model.train()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        out = model(x)
        loss = loss_fn(out, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        return loss.item()
    return train_step

def fit(epochs=100):
    train_func = train(model, optimizer, criterion)
    count, total = 0, 0
    loss_list, accuracy_list, iters = [], [], []
    for e in range(epochs):
        for X, y in train_loader:
            loss = train_func(X, y)
            count += 1
            total += len(y)
            if count % 50 == 0:
                print("loss= ", loss)
                loss_list.append(loss)
                iters.append(total)

            if count % 100 == 0:
                model.eval()   # im not sure if we can do this in pytorch. I mean evaluating the model while training! it would be great if you tell me whether this is ok or not
                out = model(X)
                out = out.detach().numpy()
                y = y.detach().numpy()
                accuracy = r2_score(y, out)   # r2_score is the scikit learn r2 score function.
                print("accuracy = ", accuracy)   # here i get wierd values and it doesn't get better over time, in contrast the loss decreased over time
                accuracy_list.append(accuracy)

    return iters, loss_list, accuracy_list
```

I know how to implement an Accuracy function in case of Classification Problem because it is using discrete values. that is clear to me because the implementation is easy and clear. I must only look which correct prediction did the model made and then calculate accuracy. but in this Case I have continuous values so that's why I couldn't implement the function myself and it surprised me that Pytorch don't have a built in function for this. so could someone maybe tell me how to implement this or where to find an Implementation of it?

another thing is where to use the evaluation and where to set the model in evaluation mode by calling the eval function. should I use it during training like I did in my Code or should I train and then test after training and if I test during training should I call the eval function as I did there or it will affect the training when the loop goes back to training mode? another thing I didn't find it also in Pytorch which is Cross validation. how should I implement it in pytorch if there is no API for it like in Keras?

Comment: What does "accuracy" for linear regression mean? The term accuracy is usually defined in machine learning and detection theory as the number of correct results divided by total samples. For continuous valued variables how you label a result as "correct" is going to be subjective.

Comment: @jodag exactly but such functions exist in sklearn and keras so how you explain that? some function exist in linear regression to tell how accurate the model is. you can see the r2_score function in sklearn for example, I'm not sure how the accuracy is implemented in keras but I think it also follow the r2_score equation. Also can you tell me how to evaluate the model if we can't measure accuracy ? one way is to look at the loss but which loss is considered good? sometimes when you normalize data, the loss value 1 is considered very bad and sometimes it is considered good so how you explain it

Comment: People added heuristics to those packages? I think the real question should be "what is meant by accuracy of regression in sklearn and keras?".

Comment: well by accuracy it is not meant as the same accuracy for discrete values, you are right on this but that's not the point. it doesnt matter what it is called. The idea is how to achieve some Equation or implementation to measure how good the best fit line is fitting on the training data. for example sklearn use this approach https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination it is called the Coefficient of determination. my Question is whether there is some built in functions in Pytorch to do this and if not how can I implement it

Comment: @jodag and let's say there is no way to implement this then based on which approach can I determine whether my Model is good or bad? I can't determine this only based on the loss because sometimes a loss value of 1 or 0.5 is considered bad or very bad, can you help me on this?

Comment: @jodag I didnt say keras is using R2 as accuracy. I said I don't know how accuracy is implemented in Keras. in Keras what we have to do is passing metrics=["accuracy"] as argument to the compile function and that would do it. I said sklearn is using R2 and also said that it is called r2_score

Comment: Ah, my mistake i misunderstood your previous comment.

Comment: I can't find any indication in keras or sklearn what is meant by accuracy for regression. There's a list of regression metrics in the [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics) which are well explained, none of these are an accuracy measure. Maybe this list will help you decide what metrics to look at?

Comment: Ah just realized there's a typo in the previous `r2` measure i gave. It should be `r2=1-torch.nn.funtional.mse_loss(target, label)/torch.var(label)`. Deleted previous comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: @jodag thnx, yes I meant metrics in sklearn. what confusing me is not only which one to use, but also how to know whether my model is good or bad. let's imagine I decide to use MSE(mean squared error), MAE or whatever which metrics of those in sklearn. how can I know whether my model is good? those metrics give continuous values between two large ranges. for example the MSE, MAE or RMSE can varie from 0 to +inf so how do I know when my model is good.for example is an MSE of 0.5 considered good? or should i use all of them and compare? what are the best practices in this field

Comment: Generally what is "good" is problem specific. Metrics are generally useful for comparative analysis. So if your system is better on all metrics than other systems it should be clear that it's better. What about if its better on some and worse on others (as is often the case). For example, say MAE is better but MSE is worse? This indicates that your system has lower average error, but there are likely a few big errors. In this case you would need to look at the problem and decide which of these types of errors are more tolerable to decide if your system is better.

Comment: So short answer is yes, use multiple metrics and compare.

Comment: A little more concrete, say one problem deals with money, and you know that an error of N implies you lose N dollars. So in this case the system with the lowest MAE leads to the highest expected value over time. Alternatively consider a trajectory estimator. In this case as long as its usually within a small margin of error then you'll hit the target, but a single big error could cause catastrophic failure. In this case MSE would is more meaningful since it penalizes large errors. You could also compute probability that the estimate is within some range by thresholding then computing accuracy.

Comment: I just did some source diving and ran an experiment and concluded keras uses binary_accuracy when you tell it to use `metrics=["accuracy"]` for regression. This is a mistake. The only reason it gives non-zero is because some of your regression targets are integers and it rounds before comparing. Try adding `0.01` to all your labels and you'll find accuracy goes to zero.

Comment: @jodag thnx for checking that,I want to check if I understand it right, you mean that keras make a rounding for the target and the prediction and then looks if they are equal ? so for example if my target is 90.9 and model prediction is 90.1 keras would consider them equal and that's how it calculate accuracy?

Comment: It only rounds the prediction. So if the label isn't an integer then you can never be counted as correct. For example, if your label and prediction are both 90.4 then it tests 90.4 == round(90.4), which is false.

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy does not exist in regression problems.
A similar measure of "accuracy" for a regression problem might be the **R-squared** score.
If you are using pytorch to train your neural networks, have a look at the package
[torchmetrics](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You may find what you need there.